# Multiple single post for custom post types

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

There is `Post` that have certain data could be viewed in `blog` nav-menu that is using `index.php` and for the single post it retrieves data from `single.php`. I also have another `custom post type` that is `client` could be viewed from `Our- client` nav menu and it is using `client template`. Now the problem is i also want a custom single page for single client so i am using `single-client.php` but when i click to any client it leads to `single.php` not `single-client. php`.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy all the content from eg. page.php, and paste this into your own template. In the top of the code, paste this

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Your template name
 * 
 */
```

After this you're able to locate the template in Page Options, when editing a page in Wordpress.
Take a look at this for more info
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/

EDIT: I just read through your problem again, and it seems like this is for you: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have used same Template Name for both pages.

```
For single-post.php
<?php 
/**
* Template Name: Your Single-Post page
*
*/
For single-client.php
<?php 
/**
* Template Name: Your Client page
```